# Adding easing to jquery css swap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-easing

HI I am trying to add some easing to a script I'm am working on and I can't get it to work right.

```
var $mainlogo = jQuery('#mainlogo');
var $menuback = jQuery('.x-navbar');
jQuery(document).scroll(function() {
    $mainlogo.css({display: jQuery(this).scrollTop()>170 ? "block":"none"});
    $menuback.css({background: jQuery(this).scrollTop()>170 ? "rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.7 )":"none"}, {
        easing: 'swing',
        duration: '2000'
    });
});
```

What Am I doing wrong? I just want it to fade in instead of an immediate appearance.

Comment: Do I need to used fade instead?
    `.fadeTo( "slow", 0.33 );`

Comment: Have a Animate-Color-Plugin included?? What's expected behaviour when scrolling back to top??